# Upgrade namespace of protobuf jar without .proto

Tags: java, jar, namespaces, protocol-buffers, package

I have a jar `myGenerated.jar` that was generated by some version of Google protocol buffer (not sure which version). That jar contains references to classes in the namespace `com.foo.bar`. I want to change it so that the classes are in the namespace `com.baz`. Unfortunately, I don't have the .proto file that was used to generate the jar- it appears to have been lost to oblivion.

Is there any way to change the namespace of the generated classes without the .proto?

Alternatively (since this would easily lead to an answer to the previous), can I reverse engineer the .proto from the existing jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to reverse engineer the original .proto file contents by using the protocol buffers reflection API. For each message type `MyMessage` that you care about, you can call `MyMessage.getDescriptor()` and then examine the descriptor using the API described [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Descriptors.Descriptor) to determine what fields are present and so forth. I do not think you can recover the .proto file contents verbatim (probably not the comments for example) but you can at least recover all the types with their field names and tag numbers. Something like `MyMessage.getDescriptor().getFile().toProto()` should give you all the information that is still available from the .proto file.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your bytecode with [dirtyJOE](http://dirty-joe.com/) and change all package names (and folders, if structured hierarchically in jar).

Answer (score 0):

Type on google or duckduck go for java decompiler.

Here are some good http://jd.benow.ca/

Choose standalone or eclipse plugin to get the original java files.